What exactly is wrong with this window/ what type of window is this?
This is a larger single hung vinyl window from what I gather but there are no text markings to help identify. The window is very loose in its tracks and easy comes out/ falls down without a prop. I was able to fit an entire wooden dowel in the deeper of the two tracks to keep it locked in place while I figure out how to fix it (img 3). I don't know much about windows but it looks like there is something missing in the tracks. Also there are small rollers on one side of the pane corresponding to the shallower track.




is there a metal tab in the track behind the wooden dowel?

@Jsotola You are on the right track but that tab would be visible on the top half of the window to catch the spring mechanism as the pane was raised.

Have you tried removing the panel from the window frame?

Second pic appears to show something out of alignment, or possibly cracked, at the top of the moving panel.

@DelphicOracle Yes I've removed it. There is nothing in the window that is not photographed.

@jsotola No there is no metal tab.

@Huesmann Yes the panel has some cracked vinyl on it but that doesn't change the shape enough to be the problem from what I can see.

Assuming this is the only window of that type in your apartment, do you know your neighbors well enough to have a look at one of theirs that function?
